IC socket for SMD on Breadboard
I'm trying to find an IC socket that will work on a breadboard for a "SMD" type pins.
Breadboard https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/dfrobot/FIT0096/7597069

I have a chip fds9934 https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/onsemi/FDS9934C/979692?s=N4IgTCBcDaIGYBMDOBOFBmALCAugXyA

I can find CONN IC DIP SOCKET 8POS TIN
https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/te-connectivity-amp-connectors/1-2199298-2/5022039 But I can't tell if this will work for my chip and breadboard?  How can I tell?


I don't think they really exist. But you can find adapter boards, which you can solder the SMD chip onto, and solder breadboard pins into.

Is there a special name used for them?

Might be easier to just get through hole FETs no?

@WesleyLee would be great but not really sure how to find out if that chip has one that will work on a breadboard.  If you know how to do this please let me know.

You just need to look for N Channel and P Channel mosfets with similar characteristics to the ones you have on the datasheet (doesnt have to be that exact FET). I think a package that might work nicely for breadboads is TO92.

They are called breakout boards. You must solder the SOIC to the board. Search Digi-Key for breakout board. There are hundreds of choices for different SMD packages.
Here are some examples from Digi-Key:


The dip socket is unlikely to work. Even if you can solder the chip into it the pins on DIP sockets are not generally long enough to go into the holes on a breadboard far enough to make a reliable connection.
What you want is a SOIC-8 to DIP-8 SMT adapter, these will have a small printed circuit board to solder the chip to, and pins that are long enough to work in the breadboard.
A search using the words I highlighted should be able to find them without much trouble.

Not that they'd be a good fit in your application, but you can find SOIC-8 ZIF (zero insertion force) adapters on breakout boards for test/burn-in/programming. Probably $30 for a low quality one that would probably be fine for hobbyist use up to hundreds of $ for models you'd use in serious production.
For a MOSFET carrying serious current (more than a few tens of mA) a breakout adapter board as mentioned is the best choice but you shouldn't be using a breadboard for that level of current anyways.

It you may need to prototype multiple small surface mount package types in the same design, TI have the DIP adapter evaluation module which is described as:

Speed up your op amp prototyping and testing with the DIP adapter evaluation module (DIP-ADAPTER-EVM), which provides a fast, easy and inexpensive way to interface with small surface-mount ICs. You can connect any supported op amp using the included Samtec terminal strips or wire them directly to existing circuits.
The DIP-ADAPTER-EVM kit supports six of the most popular industry-standard packages, including:

D and U (SOIC-8)
PW (TSSOP-8)
DGK (MSOP-8, VSSOP-8)
DBV (SOT23-6, SOT23-5 and SOT23-3)
DCK (SC70-6 and SC70-5)
DRL (SOT563-6)


It is provided as a PCB panel. The EVM usage instructions say you gently flex panel at score lines to separate boards:

